# How do you ignore input from USB while allowing from keyboard?

Tags: java, usb, cardreader

I'm tasked to replace a visitor logging system and to use magnetic strip readers to enter visitor data (from driver's licenses, etc).  We had a USB Magtek card reader that wasn't being used, and getting it working with my java project was no problem.

The issue that I'm having is that the data is being read in as if it were typed in by the keyboard, so there's no way (that I can think of) to differentiate between keyboard input and card reader input.  So, if the focus isn't in the correct field and a card is swiped, the input goes into the improper field.

I've checked the manufacturer's website and there's a little help but not much.

As The Refreshments say, "I don't need a miracle but I could use a push in the right direction."

Comment: You are talking about "fields". What fields? Why wasn't that a problem previously?

Comment: Sorry...textfields on the Java panel.

Comment: Still doesn't really answer my question though: why wasn't it a problem with the previous card reader?

Comment: Ah, a misnomer on my part.  The previous system was pen and paper.

Comment: I meant system as "way of doing things" rather than "software and equipment".